# Swift - Remove View Controller from Navigation System

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, segue

The best way that I can describe it is through and image, so i drew it out [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QL53.jpg). So, what happens is that in my table view, I press a button to add/edit information. When i am done, I press "Finish" at the bottom, which performs a simple segue back to the table view.

The Problem: Once back in the table view, the "back" button will now take me to the edit info page(which I just left) rather than the VC that came before it.

Is there any way to remove the Add/Edit info VC so that when I press "+" and "Finish" The back button will ignore the Add/Edit page?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: [image: Here is my storyboard showing the relationship between VCs]. As you can see, when you press a button on the Table VC (lefT) it will take you to the right VC. Then, when you press finish at the bottom, it will perform a segue(no code, just a control-drag segue). The problem is still that the text message VC's back button will now direct back to the right VC, rather than the one preceding it (left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a `UITableView` inside a `UINavigationController` since you have a back button, so:

**User Tap `Edit` button:** Push `EditViewController` in your `UINavigationController`

**User Tap Finish from `EditViewController`**: Save data, pop manually `EditViewController` and call `reloadData` of your `UITableView`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am having a hard time understanding what you mean. Can you please restructure your answer into a bit more sentence oriented response? The large sentence response is very hard to follow for me, as I can't exactly tell what you are referring to.

Comment: @Ryan updated, let me know if I have to add some images/code

Comment: I believe you and Ishmeet are saying the same thing - is this correct? You are saying to use "popViewController" and then reloadData on the UItableView in order to bypass the navigation controller?

Comment: @Ryan yes, I am :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to embed your complete sequence of view controllers in the navigation controller. This would maintain a stack of all the views that you would segue to. It will also give you a bcak button to go back to previous view. Alternatively, you can call the method popViewController() on navigation controller object to programmatically go to previous view. I hope that helps.

Comment: All of my view controllers are embeded in the navigation controller. Can you please elaborate? I am trying to prevent the navigation controller from going back to the Add/Edit screen, not trying to enable it

Comment: Can you post an image of your storyboard. And the code where you're going back to your tableView? Essentially you would be doing whatever you want to do with edit info screen after you press the button "Finish", and then do self.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true) to go back to your tableView!

Comment: Updated with a picture of the VC. Just to be clear - you are saying that instead of using a simple ctrl-drag segue(from the right VC back to the left VC) i need to use a "popViewController" to go back, to prevent the navigation controller's back button from pointing to the right VC from the left VC?

Comment: Yes. Because what you're currently doing will add the tableView controller again to navigation stack. Whenever you do a segue, the view is added to the navigation stack. So instead of just doing a normal drag and drop, create an action for button and do popViewController and delete your segue.